# How to format text string sent via Share menu

Tags: java, android, regex, string, android-intent

I use the following code to get TEXT sent to my app from other apps via Share menu, and display the TEXT in an EditText.

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();    
    String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();     
    String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();
    TextView txtView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWord);
    //if(receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)){
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(receivedAction) && receivedType != null) {
        if(receivedType.startsWith("text/")) {                                      
            String receivedText = receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT).toLowerCase();  
            if (receivedText != null)
            {                   
                txtView.setText(receivedText);
                txtView.requestFocus();
                ListView myList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstWord);
                myList.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                myList.setSelection(0);
            }
            else
                txtView.setText(""); 
        } 
    }
```

Everything works well, i.e., the sent text is displayed in my EditText (namely `edWord` in the above code). But the problem is the text sent via Share sometimes consists of meaningless elements or derivatives, e.g.: `"word`, `word'`, `word,` or `looked`, `books`, `tomatoes`.

Now what I want is to format the text so that it contains only real word or the base form of the word before it is added to EditText.

I've heard about `approximate string matching` or `fuzzy searching` but I have no idea how to apply it to my code. I wonder whether you can give me a little help to solve the above problem, at least with formatting/stripping non-word elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer for the first part of my question, i.e., removing non-word elements from a string (starting and/or ending a string). Here is the code with a bit of Regex algorithm that I use:

```
String receivedText = receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);  
            if (receivedText != null)                
          {                 
                receivedText = receivedText.toLowerCase();

                //Remove all non-word elements starting and/or ending a string 
                String strippedInput = receivedText.replaceAll("^\\W+|\\W+$", "");
                System.out.println("Stripped string: " + strippedInput); 

                txtView.setText(strippedInput);
                txtView.requestFocus();
                ListView myList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstWord);
                myList.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                myList.setSelection(0);
            }
```

For the second part of my question, which is about fuzzy searching, I guess it more or less involves re-coding how my app searches for results from its SQLlite database. This is still my un-answered question.